# How to apply a where clause to a specific collection

Tags: c#

The following is currently working but I need to apply a WHERE clause which I'm failing to achieve.  The current code is shown below.  My attempt is shown immediately below the current line of code.  The compiler complains with "Cannot convert expression type IEnumerablestring, double> to return type 'bool'".  Any suggestions!?
Many thanks,

**Working code**

```
return new GroupedDataCollection(data.SummaryValuations.Select(d => new GroupedData(d)));
```

**Attempt**

```
return new GroupedDataCollection(data.SummaryValuations.Where(x => x.Values.Where(y => y.Value.ContainsKey(filter))).Select(d => new GroupedData(d)));
```

**Underlying structure**

```
public class GroupedData
{
    private SummaryValuation valuation;

    public GroupedData(SummaryValuation valuation)
    {
        this.valuation = valuation;
    }
}

public class SummaryValuationGroup
{
    public string Grouping { get; set; }

    public SummaryValuation[] SummaryValuations { get; set; }
}


public class SummaryValuation : ISummaryValuation
{
    public SummaryValuation(DateTime valuationDate, SummaryGroup[] groups, Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,double>> stuff)
    {
        ....
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try this:

```
return new GroupedDataCollection(
    data.SummaryValuations.Values.SelectMany(subKeyPair => subKeyPair)
        .Where(keyPair => keyPair.Key == filter)
            .Select(keyPair => new GroupedData(keyPair.Value));
```

You should flatten the sub dictionaries and then use the where on it. (i think i got finally clear)

Answer (score 0):

Your code:

```
return new GroupedDataCollection(data.SummaryValuations.Where(x => x.Values.Where(y => y.Value.ContainsKey(filter))).Select(d => new GroupedData(d)));
```

To get all the key/value pairs where the value contains the filter:

```
return new GroupedDataCollection(data.SummaryValuations.Where(x => x.Values.Any(y => y.Value.ContainsKey(filter))).Select(d => new GroupedData(d)));
```

If this is not what you are looking for; please add type information and clearly state the goal you are trying to achieve.